# How to remove an external component of OpenFire XMPP server?

Tags: components, xmpp, openfire, shutdown

I registered an external component to OpenFire. When my component shutdown, it will keep in OpenFire server. When I restart this component, the clients' messages cannot have complete responses from this component. Because some of this component nodes has been dead.

So how to remove the dead component node? Except reboot of OpenFire.

My component code is below:

```
@Test
public void testGamma() throws ComponentException, InterruptedException {
    ExternalComponentManager componentManager = new ExternalComponentManager("172.16.5.254");
    componentManager.setSecretKey("MyBot", "mypwd");
    componentManager.setMultipleAllowed("MyBot", true);
    componentManager.addComponent("MyBot", new MyRobot());
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}

static class MyRobot extends AbstractComponent {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "This is my bot";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyWonderfulRobot";
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleMessage(org.xmpp.packet.Message message) {
        System.out.println("==================");
        send(new org.xmpp.packet.Message() {{
            this.setID(message.getID());
            this.setFrom(message.getTo());
            this.setTo(message.getFrom());
            this.setType(message.getType());
            this.setBody(message.getBody());
        }});
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Openfire probably does not see the TCP connection being closed. It will wait for a timeout, before it eventually removes the component (but that can take several minutes).

You prevent this problem by calling `componentManager.removeComponent("MyBot");` as a part of your shutdown.